# How can I add command to Gradle to be executed during build?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, scripting, build.gradle

project is Gradle based

I have this command

```
apollo schema:download --endpoint=https://*******************************/graphql schema.json
```

this downloads json file from that endpoint then I put that file under the schema(name) package, manually,
this is what I tried
I worked this command and put it under the package
is there any way to do this with scripts so this is automatically done?

I tried this

```
task<Exec>("apollo") {
commandLine("exec", "apollo schema:download --endpoint=https://*************************/graphql schema.json")
```

}

I want to do ./gradlew build and during build also run this apollo command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your build task depend on another task like this:

```
task downloadStuff {
    logger.error('Downloading dependency.')
    logger.error('Moving dependency somewhere or whatever.')
}

build {
    dependsOn downloadStuff
}
```

Make sure to add it to the root project `build.gradle` file if you have multiple and it should also be top level.